# Jquery : how does index() works?

Tags: jquery

I try to understand how the jQuery Object Accessors `index()` works. But I don't understand anything! (see http://jsfiddle.net/St4D7/)

So I have a HTML list item:

```
<ul>
<li>test 1</li>
<li>test 2</li>
<li>test 3</li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

I'd like to have the index position of items on click (like 1, 2 or 3), that's all. Please help.

PS : I don't want to use `each()` or `eq()`… just `index()`.

Comment: This works, you just forgot to add jquery into the fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/St4D7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index), `index` returns the zero-indexed position of the first element depending on the parameters you provide, in the jQuery object you call it on.

However, you also seem to be slipping up on the context of `this`.

At the time you call `$(this).index()`, `this` points to the `li`l element that was clicked on. Therefore `$(this)` contains a jQuery object containing one element.

Instead, try something like this:

```
var obj = $('ul li').click(function(){
    console.log(obj.index(this));
});
```

Comment: "If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements."

Comment: @kingjiv: Wow, didn't actually know that! It won't do the same in the current situation, but still, good to know!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in the document ready and chose jQuery as the javascript library on the left.  Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/keroger2k/St4D7/3/

Comment: Document ready is actually unneeded if you leave the default of jsfiddle which is to run the javascript onLoad.

Comment: @kingjiv True, but jsfiddle won't be responsible for the code when its on their personal website.  Better to include it than to cut and paste to their website and it not work because the DOM hasn't been loaded.

Comment: I agree, I actually prefer to change the default, just pointing out that it will have no use in the current fiddle.  "no wrap (head)" is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

A look in the source helps:

```
index: function( elem ) {
  if ( !elem || typeof elem === "string" ) {
    return jQuery.inArray( this[0],
      // If it receives a string, the selector is used
      // If it receives nothing, the siblings are used
      elem ? jQuery( elem ) : this.parent().children() ); // <-- here
  }
  // Locate the position of the desired element
  return jQuery.inArray(
    // If it receives a jQuery object, the first element is used
    elem.jquery ? elem[0] : elem, this );
},
```

As you can see, `index()` calls `inArray()`, which returns a number.

When you give no argument, it branches into the `if` and effectively calls

```
return jQuery.inArray(this[0], this.parent().children());
```

In your case, `this[0]` is the `<li>` in question and `this.parent().children()` is all the children of the parent `<ul>`. `inArray()` returns the respective position.

This is not a very efficient way to do things and it can also produce different results when compared to the index parameter of the `each()` callback, because `index()` looks at *all* children:

```
<div>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>

// this logs 0, 1 
$("div p").each(function (i) {
  console.log(i)
});

// this logs 0, 2 (!) 
$("div p").each(
  console.log( $(this).index() );
});
```